# pythonic way to iterate over this dict structure

Tags: python, dictionary, idioms

My structure is something like this in a YAML file:

```
nutrition: 
  fruits: 
    apple: 
    banana: 
    pear: 
  veggies: 
    spinach: 
    zucchini:
    squash:
  meats:
    chicken:
    fish:
    ham:
```

I load this in with yaml.load()

Not sure but likely because of the colons at the end of the leaf-elements (which I'm not sure need to be there), the entire structure is a 3-level dict. I can change the YML if needed to make it more efficient.

Now, I want to quickly iterate over the structure, and based on the leaf-level element I find (e.g. 'spinach'), I want to look up another simple dict, called 'recipes', which can have the string 'spinach' as a **substring** of its keys. This lookup dict can have keys that say 'spinach juice' or 'spinach pie' or 'chicken spinach'.

I found a way to do this, but not sure it is the right pythonic way. Here is what I have:

```
for food_class in database['nutrition']:
    for food in database['nutrition'][food_class]:
        for key, value in recipes.items():
            if re.search(food, key):
                print key
```

Any advice/pointers to make it more efficient and/or pythonic?

Comment: @alfasin What's wrong with the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.items()` so you don't need to put the dictionary lookup in the nested loop.

The foods aren't regular expressions, just strings, so use `in` rather than `re.search()`.

Since you're not using the `value` from `recipe`, you don't need `.items()`

```
for food_class, foods in database['nutrition'].items():
    for food in foods:
        for key in recipes:
            if food in key:
                print(key)
```

If you want to search for the food as a whole word, you can use `re.search(r'\b' + food + r'\b', key)` or `food in recipes.split(' ')` as the test.

Comment: What if the recipes included, say, "c**ham**pagne sauce" or "s**pear**mint tea"?

Comment: Why would that make a difference? `food in key` is just doing string matching, so it will still find it.

Comment: @ekhumoro Try `print("ham" in "champagne sauce")` and you'll see it works.

Comment: But "ham" is **not** an ingredient of "champagne sauce". I imagine the OPs regexp searches for whole words.

Comment: @ekhumoro The OP's code uses the key of a dict as the search string, it's not even an RE.

Comment: Unless you add `\b` around the RE, it doesn't look for whole words.

Comment: If it doesn't search for whole words, then it makes no sense at all. A champagne sauce does not contain any ham. Returning true for an example like that is just plain silly.

Comment: That's a different problem. I think the code he showed is really a simplified version of what he wants to do, and this part isn't relevant to the question about the looping structure.

Comment: @ekhumoro that's a great point and I had not thought of it. But I think my application can tolerate these unlikely "false matches" in the interest of faster lookups.

Comment: @Ren. Sounds like premature optimisation. How many million recipes are you searching through? And if you are handling such large data-sets, why aren't you using a database? I think you should concentrate on getting your code to work *correctly* first, and then worry about performance considerations later (if there ever are any, which I doubt).

Comment: You can use `re.search(r'\b' + food + r'\b', key)` to search for the food as a whole word.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks. Point well taken. I should admit that the application has nothing to do with recipes and that was just a scrubbed example. I expect to be dealing with thousands of keys in the "nutrition" structure and tens of thousands in the "recipes" structure. As you see I already have it working with my code example. But since I'm brand new to python (not to programming though) I wanted to ask if there are standardized efficient way of going about it. For learning.

Comment: @Ren. Even with only tens of thousands of items, I think it would be well worth investing some time in learning how to use python's [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3).

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like a job for a database, not plain text files and loops.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for your feedback and time, both on the original answer and follow-on comments. Much appreciated. I've marked this as having answered the question.